# QMake project files - selecting alternative compiler

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, qmake

The actual question:

Does qmake support custom targets with different compilers (without using different qmake commands)?  I am *not* planning to use the Qt library at all, only qmake for building.

Some background Information:

I have an existing project for which I am interested in changing the build process - we currently have an absolutely massive makefile which is... less than ideal for the situation.  It worked great a couple years ago when we had no shared code.

We now share code between a Qt application and the project I mentioned earlier.  As such, I believe switching to pro and pri files would be much cleaner and more maintainable than what we have now.

Comment: `Does qmake support custom targets with different compilers` If "different" means other than C/C++ then see `TEMPLATE=aux` and `QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS`. If by "different" you mean "another C/C++" then try to play with `QMAKESPEC`, `QMAKE_SPEC`, `QMAKE_XSPEC`. In any case, yes, it's possible.

Comment: By "different compiler" I meant "my c++ cross compiler"

But thanks, I'll do some further investigation into doing this :)

Comment: If your compiler is supported by qmake "out of the box" then all you have to do is `qmake -spec XXX`. If not then you have to write a new compiler's spec by hand.

Comment: I doubt it's supported "out of the box" with qmake - it's for petalinux.